# BSD Kernel parameter indicating shared memory in use

Tags: ipc, freebsd, bsd

Following are BSD OS based shared memory ipc kernel parameters.

```
shmall: Maximum total size of shared memory in pages (normally 4096 bytes)
shmmax: Maximum size of shared memory segment in bytes
shmmin: min shared memory segment size
shmmni: max number of shared memory identifiers
shmseg: max shared memory segments per process

kern.ipc.shmkqmax: 64
kern.ipc.shm_allow_removed: 0
kern.ipc.shm_use_phys: 0
kern.ipc.shmall: 17408
kern.ipc.shmseg: 512
kern.ipc.shmmni: 512
kern.ipc.shmmin: 1
kern.ipc.shmmax: 71303168
```

Is there any parameter to find out shm memory already allocated/in-use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sysctl` variable `kern.ipc.shmsegs`;

```
> sysctl -d kern.ipc.shmsegs
kern.ipc.shmsegs: Current number of shared memory segments allocated
```